# rewrite url query string after removing file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having issues understanding how to correctly go about rewriting a query string after removing the file extension.

My current code produces an error 500: `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Here is my htaccess rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^login/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)/?$ login.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After removing the last line (`RewriteRule ^login/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)/?$ login.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]`) the server error goes away.

What do I need to change to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules in this order:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^login/([\w=-]+)/?$ login.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the response! That removes the error but then doesn't allow any of the resources such as `css` or `javascript` to be found, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: That is due to relative paths being used. To fix you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`